# Multiple Titanium progress bars in a table view for simultaneous uploads?

Tags: iphone, progress-bar, titanium, xmlhttprequest, appcelerator-mobile

I am trying to display the progress of multiple xhr sends in a table view. This is my first shot at a table view (which also is not scrolling for some reason), and I can't figure out the appropriate way to connect the bars to the onsendstream. I appreciate any comments on the rest of my code as well.

[my window function](http://pastie.org/2035852)

Comment: I may be getting slightly confused but where in that code is the actual creation of the network object? The reason I ask this is because you stated you  are trying to connect to `onsendstream` but the API documentation uses `ondatastream` instead in the KitchenSink examples at least?

Comment: My XHR is handled in a different namespace function. There is no problem with that part of the code. The progress is streamed successfully to the log, I just can't find a way to update unique progress bars. The POSTs are occurring just fine, and I receive an alert dialog when I get a response.

Comment: By the way, `ondatastream` appears to be used for receiving, while `onsendstream` is used for sending. See the reference [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-object).

Comment: Oh snap all this time I've just read those two paragraphs as the same, good catch Micah :-)

Comment: I had to put them side by side. It hadn't crossed my mind until you asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't claim that multiple simultaneous XHRs are stable, but it is working for me in the simulator. This question was more about the specific UI task ***whether or not the XHRs are asynchronously queued***, but I appreciate any feedback about code quality or best practices. Here is the solution that I arrived at.

```
// a namespace for the UI code
myApp.ui = {};

// a function for this window
myApp.ui.createCameraWindow = function() {
    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        // I have my own custom header
        title:'',
    });

    var containerView = Ti.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor:'#85AAD7',
    });

    var tableQueue = Ti.UI.createTableView({
        backgroundColor:'#85AAD7',
        separatorColor:'#85AAD7',
        data:photosQueue, // photosQueue is an empty global array
        width:320
    });

    containerView.add(tableQueue);

    // device stores the candidate file on the system and sends data
    Ti.App.addEventListener('photoReady',function(candidate) {
        // here we an add a caption if we please
        var captionView = Ti.UI.createView({
            backgroundColor:'#FFF'
        });

        var candidateIMG = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            // the candidate file was stored with a uniqie identifier called fileStamp
            // don't forget to change resourcesDirectory to tempDirectory for use on the device
            image:Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,candidate.fileStamp + '-thumb320.png'),
            height:367,
            width:320,
            top:0,
            opacity:0.5
        });

        var captionLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            text:'caption',
            color:'#000',
            top:-180,
            textAlign:'center',
            font:{fontSize:50,fontWeight:'bold',fontStyle:'italic',fontFamily:'Cochin'},
            opacity:0.5
        });

        var captionBox = Ti.UI.createTextField({
            height:35,
            width:270,
            textAlign:'center',
            borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
        });

        var submitButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
            title:'Submit',
            color:'#000',
            selectedColor:'#FFF',
            top:220,
            width:130,
            height:35
        });

        captionView.add(candidateIMG);
        captionView.add(captionLabel);
        captionView.add(captionBox);
        captionView.add(submitButton);

        // cover the table view with the temporary caption prompt
        containerView.add(captionView);

        submitButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
            candidate.caption = captionBox.value;
            // start the xhr send from another function
            myApp.remote.createPhoto(candidate);
            // go back to the table view
            containerView.remove(captionView);

            var tempFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,candidate.fileStamp + '-thumb75.png');

            var progressBar = Ti.UI.createProgressBar({
                width:205,
                height:50,
                right:20,
                min:0,
                max:1,
                value:0,
                style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.ProgressBarStyle.PLAIN,
                color:'#FFF'
            });

            var thisRow = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                backgroundColor:'#FFF',
                layout:"vertical",
                height:75,
                fileStamp:candidate.fileStamp
            });

            // apparently the progress bar needs to be inside a view to align correctly
            var nestedView = Ti.UI.createView({
                height:75,
                width:320
            });

            var tinyThumb = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                image:tempFile,
                height:75,
                width:75,
                left:0
            });

            nestedView.add(tinyThumb);
            progressBar.show();
            nestedView.add(progressBar);
            thisRow.add(nestedView);
            photosQueue.push(thisRow);
            tableQueue.setData(photosQueue);
        });
    });

    // the xhr.onsendstream will repeatedly fire this function and send an object containing an id and e.progress
    Ti.App.addEventListener('streamProgress',function(upload) {
        // loop through the global queue
        for (i=0;i<photosQueue.length;i++) {
            // find the the array object that corresponds to the upload object
            if (photosQueue[i].fileStamp == upload.id) {
                // identifiy this object as the tableRow in the UI
                thisRow = photosQueue[i];
                // find its progress bar by knowing the view hierarchy
                var bar = thisRow.children[0].children[1];
                // update the progress bar's value
                bar.value = upload.progress;
                // update the entire tableView with new data
                tableQueue.setData(photosQueue);
            }
        }
    });

    // the xhr.onload will fire this function and send an object containing an id and a status code
    Ti.App.addEventListener('confirmation',function(upload) {
        // loop through the global queue
        for (i=0;i<photosQueue.length;i++) {
            // find the the array object that corresponds to the upload object
            if (photosQueue[i].fileStamp == upload.id) {
                // identifiy this object as the tableRow in the UI
                thisRow = photosQueue[i];
                // if the POST was successful
                if (upload.status == '201') {
                    // then make the entire row pleasing
                    thisRow.backgroundColor = 'green';
                } else {
                    // otherwise make it ugly
                    thisRow.backgroundColor = 'red';
                }
                // identify the full progress bar in the view hierarchy
                var bar = thisRow.children[0].children[1];
                // remove it regardless
                thisRow.children[0].remove(bar);
                // update the entire tableView with new data
                tableQueue.setData(photosQueue);
            }
        }
    });

    win.add(containerView);

    return win;
};
```