# Simple JavaScript object comparison

Tags: javascript, object, titanium, argument-passing, string-comparison

I am trying to pass a simple string to an event listener in order to identify an appropriate array object to modify. I understand by looking at the log (shown in comments) that what I am passing is an object and it can't be compared directly to another object's property.

Should I pass an object that has the string as a property (like the array object does), or is there a more appropriate way to reference the object as a string or call its name somehow (like the log does in the first comment)?

```
// I just want to pass a string as an argument. Here is a static example.
var timestampID = '1307740835264';
Ti.App.fireEvent('confirmation',timestampID);
```

Notice how the first log output interprets the argument as a string, but the `if` comparison recognizes it as an object.

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('confirmation',function(timestampID) { // produces "[DEBUG] fire app event: confirmation with 1307740835264"
    Ti.API.info(timestampID); // produces "[INFO] { type = confirmation; }"
    for (i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) {
        Ti.API.info(myArray[i].timestampID + ' | ' + timestampID); // produces "[INFO] 1307740835264 | [object Object]"
        if (myArray[i].timestampID == timestampID) { // will produce false
            // will never happen
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to me it looks like the `timestampID` being passed in to the handler is an object, however from the second statement (and accompanying [INFO] comment), I have absolutely no idea what properties it has. Let's assume that it has a property called timestamp. Then your `if` statement should be

```
if (myArray[i].timestampID === timestampID.timestamp)
```

But that's about all I can glean from this code snippet I'm afraid.

**UPDATE**: OK, I see how you're triggering the event. The Titanium API is bafflingly obtuse on this point (it looks like the [help for fireEvent](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.2/Titanium.App.fireEvent-method.html) is wrong: two parameters called "name"?). There are no examples that I can see. However it does say that what you pass in as the data is (must be?) serialized as JSON.

Now that I know that, looking at the second statement's [INFO] line it makes more sense. It's a string that has the JSON data. Your data is missing since it was a string value. Try this to fire:

```
Ti.App.fireEvent('confirmation', { timestampID: '1307740835264' } );
```

and this in the event handler:

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('confirmation', function (data) {
  for (i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) {
    if (myArray[i].timestampID === data.timestampID) { 
        ...code...
    }
}
```

});

Comment: what's a timestamo? did you mean timestamp?

Comment: What I am trying to pass is just the timestamp as an argument (I am just choosing to call it a timestampID). I don't need to send any other properties beyond just the string. It works everywhere else where I am receiving the timestampID and using it as a string, but an `if` comparison strictly recognizes it as an object.

Comment: @Micah: then I'm lost I'm afraid. The code you've shown is too little to reveal the problem.

Comment: @Micah: I think I understand now. See my changes.

Comment: Thanks. You uncovered the issue that the argument itself needs to be JSON, but in practice I am just passing an object like you originally suggested. You can see the use case [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274133/multiple-titanium-progress-bars-in-a-table-view-for-simultaneous-uploads). Although I think my real question should have been this: If I declare `var myObject = {};`, then how do I produce the string "myObject" by calling `myObject.??????`?

Comment: @Micah: You can't. There is no way to. Add a name property to the object, or add a toString method that returns the name of the object:

myObject.toString = function () { return "myObject"; };

Answer (score 0):

Either write a comparison function or find the scalar property (Number or String) that you want to compare.